# how to translate this sql to squelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, typescript, sequelize.js

i need join another table by two field like this,how to get this by squelize

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    Issue
    LEFT OUTER JOIN File1 ON File1.project_id = Issue.project_id 
    AND File1.file_path = Issue.file_path 
WHERE
    Issue.project_id = 1 
    AND version_id =1
```

so I try to use this

```
class Issue extends Model<attributes, creationAttributes> {
    ...

  @BelongsTo(() => File1, {
    foreignKey: "project_id",
    targetKey: "projectId",
    constraints: false,
  })
  file!: File1;
}


Issue.findAll({
    where:{
        projectId:1,
        versionId:1
    },
    include:[File1]
})
```

but this code translate to sql is

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    Issue
    LEFT OUTER JOIN File1 ON File1.project_id = Issue.project_id 
WHERE
    Issue.project_id = 1 
    AND version_id =1
```

it's not i want to get

Comment: Which table does the column "version" belong to?  You may be creating an "implied inner join" if it is from table file1

Comment: make that `inlcude` option [an object](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level) with its own `where` clause, since you're trying to join on multiple conditions.

Comment: 'version' belong to 'Issue'

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Issue.findAll({
    where:{
        projectId:1,
        versionId:1
    },
    include:[{
      model: File1,
      as: 'File1',
      where: {
        file_path: '$Issue.file_path$',
      }
    }]
})
```

Or you could refer to this docs: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#eager-loading-filtered-at-the-associated-model-level

Comment: '$Issue.file_path$' is not work,I try '  file_path: { [Op.eq]: Sequelize.col("Issues.file_path") }',its ok

Answer (score 0):

inspired by @SayedKhaidirAli's answer and [docs](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/eager-loading/#eager-loading-filtered-at-the-associated-model-level), this is useful

```
Issue.findAll({
where:{
    projectId:1,
    versionId:1
},
include:[{
  model: File1,
  where: {
    file_path: { [Op.eq]: Sequelize.col("Issues.file_path") },
  }
}]})
```